# ReadMe file won't allow me to commit and push xcode changes to github

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have an existing xcode project and repo on Github. I recently added a ReadMe file which was suggested by Github but now I can no longer commit and push changes to Github. I keep getting an out of date message. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to pull first.

Comment: Thank you for responding

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience of adding README.md with the same error.

If you don't want to `git pull`, because the remote version in Github is outdated.

You can also force push all local branches using:

> **$ git push -f origin master**

The following commands in the Terminal will push your local Xcode project to remote Github.

```
cd <drag location folder of project>

git init

git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `git pull`.

If you're using the command line, navigate to the directory of the repository and run `git pull`. If you're using another interface, the steps may be a bit different.

Comment: Thank you @BrianaSwift for being so clear and detailed with your response